# Spark - ignoring corrupted files

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In the ETL process that we are managing, we are receiving sometimes corrupted files. 
We tried this Spark configuration and it seems it works (the Spark job is not failing because the corrupted files are discarded):

```
spark.sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles", "true")
```

But I don't know if there is anyway to know which files were ignored. Is there anyway to get those filenames?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe this can help https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/spark-sql/handling-bad-records.html

Comment: Thanks for trying to help but I am using emr-5.26.0 (Hadoop distribution:Amazon 2.8.5, Applications:Spark 2.4.3) but it seems that it is just present in spark  Databricks Runtime 3.0, not in EMR.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-whatsnew-history.html

Comment: thanks for trying to help @gorros but I already took a look to the doc before posting this question here, and I didn't find anything similar using spark in EMR. It seems other people posted same question and same issues. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54540468/spark-row-level-error-handling-how-to-get-error-message-at-row-level

Comment: what did you do in the end

Comment: @Topde at the end we just decided to go through the executor logs.

Comment: I tried that and could find the answer still, where in the logs?

Answer (score 2):

One way is look through your executor logs. If you have setup following configuratios to true in your spark configuration.

RDD: spark.files.ignoreCorruptFiles
DataFrame: spark.sql.files.ignoreCorruptFiles

Then spark will log corrupted file as a WARN message in your executor logs.

Here is code snippet from Spark that does that:

```
      if (ignoreCorruptFiles) {
        currentIterator = new NextIterator[Object] {
          // The readFunction may read some bytes before consuming the iterator, e.g.,
          // vectorized Parquet reader. Here we use lazy val to delay the creation of
          // iterator so that we will throw exception in `getNext`.
          private lazy val internalIter = readCurrentFile()

          override def getNext(): AnyRef = {
            try {
              if (internalIter.hasNext) {
                internalIter.next()
              } else {
                finished = true
                null
              }
            } catch {
              // Throw FileNotFoundException even `ignoreCorruptFiles` is true
              case e: FileNotFoundException => throw e
              case e @ (_: RuntimeException | _: IOException) =>
                logWarning(
                  s"Skipped the rest of the content in the corrupted file: $currentFile", e)
                finished = true
                null
            }
          }
```

Comment: How could I view these logs from PySpark please

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve it?

If not, may be you can try the below approach:

1. Read everything from the location with that ignoreCorruptFiles setting
2. You can get the file names each record belongs to using the [input_file_name](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#input_file_name()) UDF. Get distinct names out.
3. Separately get list of all the objects in the respective directory
4. Find the difference.

Did you use a different approach?